# How do I integrate an Audio Unit to an app

Tags: cocoa, core-audio

How do I integrate an audio unit into an application.  I may not be familiar with the concept of components.  I can open them in AUlab but I want to use it with a main.

Comment: 4 years later I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. Did you ever get this accomplished and would you be willing to share some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Programming an AudioUnit host is a good amount of work.  A couple of resources to get you started:

1. The [Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a section on [Hosting](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH6-DontLinkElementID_5) which scratches the surface of what you need to learn.  I would start by reading the entire guide, and examining the provied [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/MusicAudio/index-date.html#doclist).
2. Also, check out the [ardour](http://ardour.org/) code base for some example code on how they host audio units in their application.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial question. You have a fair amount of work ahead of you.

Start [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH6-DontLinkElementID_5) with the Apple documentation.
You will need to learn to configure CoreAudio, and then build AU "graphs".